# How do I log into a gnome session?

Tags: gnome, lightdm

I've upgraded my Ubuntu installation from 11.04 to 11.10. If I choose gnome at the lightdm login screen the system logs me into a unity session. If I choose any other option the system logs me also into a unity session (I've installed fluxbox as well and it is not possible to start a fluxbox session). Does somebody has the same problem or could point me to the right log file to check for this problem?

Comment: Can you double check that it's gdm and not lightdm? lightdm is the default in 11.10

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I edit the question.

Comment: That is not really an answer since it leaves the 'original' problem unsolved. I switched from lightdm to gdm by

    sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm

which solved this issue for me. Unfortunately I'm not allow to post an answer to this question until 7 or 8 hours have passed. Argh.

Comment: It's strange that the problem was fixed by changing display managers? What are the names of all the selectable session types listed in lightdm? What are the names of all the selectable session types listed in gdm? Generally speaking, to get a GNOME 3 session you would choose GNOME, and to get a GNOME 3 Failsafe session which is very similar to the non-Unity GNOME 2 interface that was available prior to Oneiric (called Ubuntu Classic), you would choose GNOME Classic (or GNOME Failsafe).

Comment: Yeah. It's very strange. But both gdm as well as lightdm seem to offer the content of /usr/share/xsessions/

Comment: The content of /usr/share/xsessions is: fluxbox.desktop    guest-restricted.desktop
gnome-classic.desktop   ubuntu-2d.desktop
gnome-classic-guest-restricted.desktop ubuntu.desktop
gnome.desktop    xsession.desktop
gnome-fallback.desktop   xterm.desktop
gnome-shell.desktop                                         That is what both login managers offer me.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo apt-get uninstall gdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```